# Translating dates in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a list with dates, representations in rows. The task is to represent the date as a datetime object, or as a date in the format DD.MM.YYYY. But the dates are written this way:

- Dec. 3, 2008
- Feb. 13, 2009
- June 26, 2009
- March 20, 2010
- April 6, 2013
- Sept. 13, 2015

And I don't know how to convert them to the DD.MM.YYYY format.

I tried to use this code:

```
try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, '%b. %d, %Y').strftime('%d.%m.%y')
except ValueError:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%d.%m.%y')
```

but it was not suitable for dates with September.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), it seems that you'll have to replace `Sept` with `Sep` on your own.

Comment: Something like this: `strptime(mydate.replace('Sept', 'Sep'), '%b. %d, %Y').strftime('%d.%m.%y')`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than coding your own it is simplest to use a date parser from a library. Assuming your dates are strings in a List named `dateslist` then you could use the following to give a List of datetime objects:

```
from dateutil import parser

dates = []

for entry in datelist:
    dates.append(parser.parse(entry))
    
print(dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you should not use any third-party libraries AND date strings are going to be with different month names (like Sept, Sep, September):

```
string_date = string_date.split()
string_date[0] = string_date[0][:3]
" ".join(string_date)
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%d.%m.%y')
```

if the problem is only with september - use @OrenIshShalom method

if you can use third-party libraries and all input date string will be different format - use @user19077881 method